How to make a dropdown list that can send data to Django (to Models) with Kivymd?
I found a recipe where I could save the results into a variable using the instructions in the KivyMD documentation, but some of the codes shared there did not work in my editor. So, the versions I use are: "python 3.11", "kivymd version 1.2.0" and the MDDropDownItemText module I need to use is not included in kivymd. For this reason, I cannot give special IDs to items and I cannot save the selected values ​​into a variable. What can be done here?
My goal was to record whether the user was male or female in the model I created in Django. And I thought I could do this by transferring the result from the drop down list into a variable. I tried following the instructions in the Kivymd documentation, but I encountered the results I mentioned above.
KivyMD documentation: text

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This question stemmed from me looking in the wrong place. I'm leaving it below for someone to meet their needs (just in case).
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

KV = '''
MDScreen:

   MDRaisedButton:
       id: button
       text: "Press me"
       pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
       on_release: app.menu_open()
'''


class Test(MDApp):
   def menu_open(self):
       menu_items = [
           {
               "text": f"Item {i}",
               "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.menu_callback(x),
           } for i in range(5)
       ]
       MDDropdownMenu(
           caller=self.root.ids.button, items=menu_items
       ).open()

   def menu_callback(self, text_item):
       print(text_item)

   def build(self):
       self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
       self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
       return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()

More detailed data is in the documentation: enter link description here
